# How to get Data from Observable angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ngrx-store

I got stucked trying to get cars$ Observable variable into the CarListComponent.ts , I I only can access it by the html template, but I need get it from the onInit Component ,

why I' m trying to do:

-Subscribe to the cars$ variable and then do a map into initTable method

```
export class CarListComponent implements OnInit {
    model = new TableModel();
    cars$: Observable<ICar[]>;

    constructor(private store: Store<fromStore.CarState>) {
        this.store.dispatch(fromActions.requestLoadCars());
        this.cars$ = this.store.select(fromSelectors.cars);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initTable();
    }

    initTable() {
        this.model.header = [
            new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Brand" }),
            new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Model" }),
            new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Year" }),
            new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Price" }),
            new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Created At" }),
        ];

        this.cars$.subscribe((carList) => {
            carList.map((car) => {
                this.model.data.push([
                    new TableItem({ data: car.brand.name }),
                    new TableItem({ data: car.model }),
                    new TableItem({ data: car.year }),
                    new TableItem({ data: car.price }),
                    new TableItem({ data: car.createdAt }),
                ]);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok what is wrong with this code? Please put your code in stackblitz

Comment: Now  `this.model.data` has value and you can access it in `CarListComponent.ts`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
export class CarListComponent implements OnInit {


  model = new TableModel();
  cars: ICar[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromStore.CarState>) {
    this.store.dispatch(fromActions.requestLoadCars());
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initTable();
  }

  initTable() {
    this.model.header = [
        new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Brand" }),
        new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Model" }),
        new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Year" }),
        new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Price" }),
        new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Created At" }),
    ];

    this.store.select(fromSelectors.cars).subscribe((carList) => {
        this.cars = carList.map((car) => {
              this.model.data.push([
                  new TableItem({ data: car.brand.name }),
                  new TableItem({ data: car.model }),
                  new TableItem({ data: car.year }),
                  new TableItem({ data: car.price }),
                  new TableItem({ data: car.createdAt }),
              ]);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help anyone. An answer should not be a "here, copy this code". It should explain the problem and teach the OP or any other reader who might stumble upon this answer.